# Как безопасно удалить данные с диска (SSD, HDD)?

Tags: windows, безопасность, файловая-система, hdd, ssd

Хотел бы узнать по поводу безопасного удаления данных с HDD и с SSD дисков. Часто приходится хранить важные документы на домашней машине и не хотелось бы чтобы кто-то смог их восстановить в случае кражи компьютера. Достаточно ли для SSD и для HDD перезаписи файлов через sdelete (ОС Windows) в 5/10/30 проходов, чтобы никто не смог никогда восстановить эти документы? Если перезаписать файл условно 5 раз, то его уже нельзя будет никогда восстановить? Помогите разобраться пожалуйста, и посоветуйте лучшие способы уничтожения важных файлов для ОС Windows и Linux.

Спасибо.

Comment: Для SSD наверное лучше использовать функции Secure Erase из программ производителей конкретных носителей

Comment: А для HDD вполне достаточно однократной перезаписи. Сказки про супер-оборудование, которое тащит старые данные по краевой либо остаточной намагниченности - они сказки и есть.

Comment: *не хотелось бы чтобы кто-то смог их восстановить в случае кражи компьютера.* Любой криптоконтейнер с вменяемым паролем или с аппаратным ключом.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендуется к установке Shred OS.
[Shred OS](https://github.com/PartialVolume/shredos.x86_64) - это open-source система UNIX-like, под лицензией GPLv3+ и 0BSD для форматирования жёстких дисков.

Способы форматирования диска:

- Fill With Zeros - Заполняет устройство нулями (0x00), только один круг.
- Fill With Ones - Заполняет устройство единицами (0xFF), только один круг.
- RCMP TSSIT OPS-II - Стандарт технической безопасности Королевской канадской конной полиции, OPS-II.
- DoD Short - 3 коротких прохода форматирования американского Министерства обороны 5220.22-M (проходы 1, 2 и 7).
- DoD 5220.22M - 7 полных проходов форматирования Американского министерства обороны 5220.22-M.
- Gutmann Wipe - Метод Питера Гутмана (Безопасное удаление данных из магнитной и твердотельной памяти).
- PRNG Stream - Заполняет устройство потоком от PRNG.

Ссылка на Shred OS - [Ссылка](https://github.com/PartialVolume/shredos.x86_64)